# Fibonacci's sequence to calculate growth of a family

Tags: fibonacci-numbers, word-problem

I'm trying to solve the following mathematical dilemma:

> On the 1st of July 2000 a Lizard bears 4 babies. On the 1st July 2001
>   each of those Lizard bears in turn 4 babies. And so on. Assumed that
>   each Lizard lays eggs once in its life, how many Lizards are born on
>   the 1st July 2006 ?

I'd assume the result is 4^7 = 16384

Is it correct? Also, I wonder if the Fibonacci sequence can be used for the resolution of this dilemma?

Comment: Where is the dilemma?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is $4^7=16384$  The exponent is just the year minus $1999$

The Fibonacci sequence does not play into it because the recurrence is just $a_{n+1}=4a_n$, which is different from the one in Fibonacci.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer!